# Transferring data ( DataTable) from powershell pipeline to Commandlet C#

Tags: c#, powershell, pipeline, powershell-cmdlet

I want to transfer DataTable from Powershell Pipeline to C# based commandlet. At the moment, it traverses the whole data table and transfers just single DataRow which entirely is bad. I want full data table to be transferred from PowerShell pipeline to commandlet parameters.

Following is my C# commandlet code where Parameter 'ParameterValue' expects a complete data table.

```
[Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Set, "LinkParameter")]  
public class SetLinkParameter : PSCmdlet
{
    [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = true)]
    public string ParameterName { get; set; }

    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = true, Position = 1)] // The data or dataTable appear in this variable
    public PSObject ParameterValue { get; set; }
}
```

and the following is the script which I am executing.

```
$table = New-Object system.Data.DataTable 'DataTable'

$newcol = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn ColumnStringA,([string]); $table.columns.add($newcol)
$newcol = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn ColumnStringB,([string]); $table.columns.add($newcol)
$newcol = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn ColumnLongC,([long]); $table.columns.add($newcol)


$row = $table.NewRow()
$row.ColumnStringA = ("ColumnStringA")
$row.ColumnStringB = ("ColumnStringB")
$row.ColumnLongC =  45781547

$table.Rows.Add($row) 

$table| Set-LinkParameter
```

While, above Set-LinkParameter command executes and ParameterValue get's its value there, it's not data table at all. This becomes a collection of DataRow or single DataRow. PErhaps pipeline executes the collection and it enumerates simply.
How can this be stopped? I want a full-fledged data table at receiving side rather than data rows or single data row. On the other hand **I want it to be set via Pipeline manner.**

Comment: This is a know behavior, see also: https://github.com/pester/Pester/issues/386. The workaround is as @PetSerAl stated (a comma in front of the input or use [`Write-Output -NoEnumerate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/Write-Output?view=powershell-4.0) `$table | Set-LinkParameter` in ps4 and later)

Comment: Thanks Guys. Yes it worked that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As PetSerAI and iRon mentioned about the way. We can use both techniques. Write-Output -NoEnumerate or put , before dataTable variable before passing to pipeline. It would not enumerate and pass individual rows but will pass the entire collection collectively.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get reference to the datable from that single datarow:

```
if($dt.GetType().Name -eq "DataRow"){$dt = $dt.Table }
```